# How should I style my German doctoral title in English documents?

Tags: germany, language, titles

I hold a Dr. rer. nat. title from the computer science institute at a German university. I am now writing a job application that I will send to a German organization, but since it has many international employees and the advertisement itself was in English, I decided to write the application in English (assuming that some of the decision makers may not speak German well).

My biggest problem in the translation is my title. In the German original, I use Dr. rumtscho in the CV header and a couple of other places. However, all translated versions I considered have drawbacks:

- keep it as **Dr. rumtscho**. This is idiomatic in German, but I think it's totally strange in English and may make people think that I forgot to pay attention to the header when translating.
- Style myself as **rumstcho, PhD**. While I refer to my title as "PhD" in informal conversation in English, I believe it is officially not permissible to "translate" the title.
- Style myself as **rumtscho, Dr. rer. nat.** This looks weird both in English and in German, and for people unfamiliar with the "there is no traditional doctor title for computer scientists, so we just reuse one" attitude of German universities, they may think I come from a biology or chemistry background.

Which option is likely to be best received? Is the answer different when preparing English-language official documents to be read by Germans and by native English speakers?

Comment: It's weird to have any title in your header in the US.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim hehe, this is practically the only place in my life I use the title, please don't take that small joy away from me :) but seriously, I think it is a good idea to have the title visible somewhere on the job application outside of the education area of the CV, and if I move it somewhere else like the cover letter signature, the problem is the same.

Comment: I suppose you are applying to jobs where a doctoral degree is required or at least it’s very uncommon not to have one. In this case, I feel that using the title is at best pointless and at worst comes of as arrogant. In my applications (in Germany), I never used my doctoral title next to my name anywhere.

Comment: "I think it is a good idea to have the title visible somewhere on the job application outside of the education area of the CV" Probably it won't matter.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Is it not common to use full titles (with several designations if applicable) in formal contexts in German academia? That is the impression I got from most of the web pages of professors that I have seen.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Thank you for the suggestion. I chose Academia on purpose, because I got the title from an academic institution, and I would love to know how the academic world deals with this situation. That it's for a job is just a bit of context, I hope that I can use the same rules on all official documents where naming the title is appropriate.

Comment: @GoodDeeds: Web pages and applications have considerably different target audiences. The former includes students, journalists, bureaucrats, etc., who may not know things like that professors very likely also have a doctoral degree (and it doesn’t really matter if they don’t), may be impressed by the degree, etc. An application within academia is quite a different thing, in particular if the position requires a doctoral degree. It will primarily read by people who also have a doctoral degree. Also, I rarely see designations like *rer. nat.* on professors’ webpages.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim If you have a doctoral degree in Germany it's very common to be addressed as "Dr. John Doe" in public life (e.g. mail)

Comment: @user And that includes CV headers? I bring it up because the OP was asking for English standards. The standard in NA would be no title at all (unsure about UK)

Comment: @GoodDeeds It depends on the field. Engineers tends to like them, mathematicians and physicists are less eager to have their complete title mentioned everywhere. Given that virtually everybody holds a doctoral degree and most a professor, it doesn't matter among professors anyway. YMMV.

Comment: Since nobody seems to have commented on this: you say you think Dr. [name] is "totally strange in English". I disagree wholeheartedly: it's absolutely fine in English and I didn't even bat an eye at it. (I know your question has other aspects.)

Comment: @GregMartin, outside of academia, mostly only medical doctors and doctors of divinity are addressed as "Dr. So-and-so". To address a STEM Ph.D. as "Dr. X" would seem very pretentious almost anywhere but in a lecture hall. On the other hand, I think a CV/resume is a perfectly reasonable place to include your full titles, even if seeking an industrial rather than academic position.

Comment: I would expect English speakers who are on the selection committee for a position at a German institution to be at least somewhat familiar (and probably very familiar) with German practice in this area, even if their German is otherwise lacking. So I'd tend to use the German conventions if the English ones can't be made to fit, even if the document is otherwise in English.

Answer (score 25):

Don't overthink it. Both "Dr." and "Dr.rer.nat." would be OK, "PhD" would be inaccurate. The key information is the line in your CV where you point out that you have completed your doctoral degree.

(As relevant context: I am a native German speaker and have experiences in Germany both as a selection committee member and as a successful applicant.)

Comment: This. Also my English-language CV which I've also used for applications in Germany (and which contains grades from Germany) has the title/name line **cbeleites** (with full first name, though) and the doctoral degree in the educaton section. My doctoral degree stays Dr. rer. nat. wherever I go (looking into my CV I actually did not specify that, I give the thesis title, university and mark - but of course the certificates say so) and my Diplom stays Diplom as well. The postdoc jobs I've encountered in Germany actually did not formally require a doctorate - equivalent research experience was OK

Comment: ... was OK as well (I've actually been at such positions for several years without being PhD/Dr. rer. nat.). (The hard/formal requirements I've met have been the other way round: doctorate not older than x.)

Comment: Exactly. Holding a Dr. doesn't imply holding a PhD. Holding a PhD, you *might* be allowed to call yourself a Dr. in Germany depending mostly on where you graduated.

Comment: Dr. rer. nat. applied to computer science is no weirder than PhD applied to engineering.

Answer (score 7):

#### In English, "Dr." means you completed your PhD.

In English, anyone who has completed a PhD is entitled to be called "Doctor", regardless of the subject that they'd completed their degree in. Whether that degree is in IT, Physics, English Literature, or Underwater Basket Weaving, if you've completed a PhD, you're entitled to be called "Doctor". Then, when you list your degree on your resume or CV, you specify what your PhD was in.

Judging by the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._rer._nat.) about the Dr.rer.nat degree, it's basically equivalent to a PhD in science, so the same rule would apply.

In spoken language, you'd often be referred to as "Doctor [Surname]" as a formal title, unless you've got a higher-ranking title to be referred to as instead (e.g. "Professor [Surname]", or a title of nobility like "Sir [Given Name]" or "Lord [Surname], Baron of [Place]").

You can also be entitled to be referred to as "Doctor [Surname]" if you've completed a medical degree and become a licensed medical doctor, even though their degrees are "only" equivalent to a Master's Degree, but that wouldn't apply in your case. If there's any confusion whether someone's a medical doctor or a PhD graduate, you can just ask them.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how this answers my situation, it seems that you are just describing the common spoken-language usage in English-speaking countries, which I already know. The problems here: 1) I didn't complete a PhD, I completed a Dr.rer.nat, and 2) this is an official written document, and I have not seen people use the "Dr. rumtscho" style in one of those. I wanted to know how a native German reader will react to that style, as opposed to their reaction to one of the other styles.

Comment: PhD and Dr.rer.nat are the same thing in English, judging by the wikipedia page on the latter. Like I said, it doesn't matter whether you complete a PhD in English Literature or Theoretical Physics, either way you're still just referred to as "Doctor".

Comment: I would say that English speakers (at least American English) take "Dr." to mean that you've completed either a PhD at a US university _or_ some other non-professional degree with roughly equivalent requirements, i.e. 5+ years of graduate study including a dissertation. (Or that you're a medical doctor.) Of course the US perspective might not apply in Germany; I couldn't say.

Answer (score 3):

**It is typical to refer to people having some kind of doctorate as "Dr FirstName LastName" in British academia.** Note that there is no dot after the "Dr", American usage may wary. For example, look at the staff list of my department here:

https://www.swansea.ac.uk/staff/science/compsci/

A Dr rer nat is a perfectly fine doctorate, and in fact, the kind of doctorate several people in the list above have.

Writing FirstName LastName, PhD is what one would do to clarify that the doctorate is in fact a PhD; or just if it is a PhD and more convenient to have it after the name (maybe the person is also  a Sir and one wants to express both, etc).

Comment: "Writing FirstName LastName, PhD is what you would do to clarify that the doctorate is in fact a PhD" but the doctorate is not a PhD. The doctorate is a Dr. rer. nat.. Calling yourself a PhD in Germany when you are a Dr. rer. nat. might get you a fine (see second paragraph of section "Ph.D. in Deutschland" [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ph.D.#Ph.D._in_Deutschland) and the referenced source).

Comment: @wimi Well, if one doesnt have a PhD one should not clarify that one has one, right? I'll replace the "you" with "one" to make clear that this does not refer to the OP, but to a generic person.

Answer (score 2):

rumtscho, Dr. rer. nat. (CS)

Does that work for you? If you were to move to the US, or some other English speaking countries, Dr. rumtscho would probably be enough. But if you remain in Germany/Austria... then it might be best to keep it formal and as awarded. Especially so if you are writing to a German organization. The English speakers will just have to deal with it.

Hmm. Maybe
rumtscho, Dr. rer. nat. (Computerwissenschaften)

Comment: More likely (Informatik)

Comment: @JeffE, maybe. Not knowing the popular usage, I just used the literal translation (via google translate). But something like that, as appropriate.

Comment: This looks wrong to me, I’ve never seen Dr. or Dr. rer. nat. after the name.

Comment: @PieterNaaijkens I have also never seen these after the name, but the only style that is commonly seen in English (rumtscho, PhD) is illegal, so I will have to use something uncommon/wrong looking.

Comment: No. Dr. always precedes the last name in German writing (*vorangestellter Titel*), unlike e.g. a *Diplom* or *Magister* (if you're in Austria, even those may go first).

Comment: @henning--reinstateMonica, but the styling is specifically intended for English speakers. I'm only responding to that. It is awkward because of the differences in the cultures.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Arno's reply:

Academic titles are not controlled by law in the UK. It is generally considered that those holding a substantive doctoral degree are entitled to be called Dr, and that non-surgical medical practitioners are called Dr by courtesy, but this is custom, not law. The National Health Service, for example, refuses to accord genuine doctors their title :)
Thus, as Arno says, "Dr rumtscho" is perfectly idiomatic and normal.
HOWEVER, it is also, in British academia, customary not to use titles in CV headers - the headline of a CV should just be your name. At some point in your CV, you list your qualifications, and that's where you say "Dr. rer. nat." So you have to decide whether you're doing a British-style application, or a German-style application translated into English:)

Having said that, there's a member of staff in my (British) university who insists their students write to them as "Dr. Dr. blah". As you can imagine, this flags them as insecure and pretentious.

Comment: My brother (who has a doctorate in medicine, with postnominal letters DM) **is** listed as "Dr" on his NHS hospital website, along with many other doctors. Not sure whether he is one of the "genuine doctors" you mention.

Comment: In clinical settings in the U.K. allowing people who aren’t registered medical practitioners to use the title Dr risks misleading patients and others into thinking that person is medically qualified. This has patient safety and legal risks - eg potentially falling foul of The Medical Act 1983 (https://www.gmc-uk.org/registration-and-licensing/the-medical-register/a-guide-to-the-medical-register/unregistered-medical-practice).